# Elasticsearch low ngram causing additional irrelevant results

Tags: python, elasticsearch, n-gram

On this Elasticsearch machine, I have an ngram filter of minimum size 3.

```
'my_ngram': {
    'type': 'nGram',
    'max_gram': 50,
    'min_gram': 3
},
```

This works great for searching for things like "dim sum", where I am given things back relating to dim sum.

However, when I put in a search for "steak", since the ngram is so low, I get results for things containing "steam" and "steal".

After bumping the ngram minimum up to 5 and reindexing, that fixes "steak" returning other results, but now searches for "dim sum" return nothing.

The search is being run from python 2.7

```
search = Search(doc_type=('post',), index='sitename')
search = search.query('multi_match', query='dimsum', fields=['title^2', 'content'], operator='and')
response = search.execute()
```

Can anyone tell me how to tune this so that searches are a little more "on point"? I don't know what other information is relevant to this but I'll share more if needed.

Comment: Try not using that nGram analyzer during search, but only at indexing time. In your mapping, you need to specify `"search_analyzer": "standard"` for the `title` and `content` fields in order to override the `nGram` analyzer that kicks in at indexing time.

Comment: Have you been able to try this out?

Comment: I hadn't. There was a point in time where we needed an autocomplete feature and this was perfect for that. Removing the ngram l fixes the problem for us at this point. I do believe our solution, if we ever bring this back, is to just have 2 indexes, one with and without an ngram. I'll most likely delete this question as I dont know if I'll ever get around to testing our your suggestion. Thank you for your help though, I appreciate it.

Comment: Feel free to explain your real use case at some point and I'm sure we'll find a much better solution than having to duplicate your indices.